# User ActiveModel Serializer json_api adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I am working to return json response with format following the guide from http://jsonapi.org using AMS. however default AMS adapter does not support this. I try to enable the ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter::JsonApi suggested here: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers but when I boot rails s, I got the following error :

config/initializers/ams.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`config' for ActiveModel::Serializer:Class (NoMethodError)

your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using AMS 0.10+? If you are using any version prior to 0.10, you will get this error.